# Show objects properly as choices in django forms choicefield

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, choicefield

I am working on some kind of testing application. I have two models for tests and users answers:

```
class TestModel(AbstractDatetimeModel):
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    answer_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    answer_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class AnswerModel(AbstractDatetimeModel):
    ANSWERS = (
        ('1', 'A'),
        ('2', 'B')
    )
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(TestModel)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ANSWERS)
```

And I have a form, where candidate (user) can answer each question. To implement this I use a view `formset_factory`:

```
def communicative_test(request):
    questions = TestModel.objects.all()
    question_formset = formset_factory(form=TestForm, extra=questions.count())
    question_formset = question_formset(initial=[{'candidate': request.user, 'question': x.number,
                                                  'answer_1': x.answer_1, 'answer_2': x.answer_2} for x in questions])
    return render(request, 'testing/communicative.html', locals())
```

On a form I need to show ChoiceField, where choices should be data from fields answer_1 and answer_2. Here is this form:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer_1 = forms.CharField()
    answer_2 = forms.CharField()
    VARIANTS = (
        ('answer_1', answer_1),
        ('answer_2', answer_2)
    )
    variants = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VARIANTS, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = TestAnswer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Problem is that on a page these answers displays as radio buttons with following labels:

```
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f36248ef5d0>
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f36248ef650>
```

I need to display it properly.

Comment: what you are trying to do here `('answer_1', answer_1)` can't work. why do you have `answer_1` and `answer_2` in the form at all?  they look like multiple choice questions so don't you just want to collect the user's choice (eg A/B/C/D) rather than descriptive answer values?  you need to think through more clearly what you're trying to do

Comment: Ther are not multiple choices, because they are used in ChoiceField as choices. I agree with you, that it would be much more easier to just show ChoiceFiled with A or B. But for user it's not enough. User needs to see the text of each variant. These texts comes from TestModels answer_1 and answer_2 fields.

Comment: you are confusing between what is displayed to the user (answer text) and the value that should be submitted to the form (eg A/B/C/D or just 0/1/2/3)

Comment: No, I am not confusing. I just need to show, that I explained in quesiton and in description. Submition of the form is another thing to do. But at first, I need to solve current problem.

Comment: what I mean is, you are trying to solve a problem you have created for yourself by trying to do something that is not the right thing to do

Comment: @Anentropic, thanks! Yes, you are right) That was a 18 hours without a sleep and I really confused. But now I solve the problem another way, using custom templatetags to get questions answers text for A/B variants. Bellow I will give details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as @Anentropic mentioned, I was not on the right way.
And he is right, because I need to submit only answer A or B. But for user on the form I need to display text for these answers from Test model. So I wrote two templatetags for this.
    class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
    class Meta:
        model = TestAnswer
        fields = '__all__'

def communicative_test(request):
    questions = TestModel.objects.all()
    QuestionFormSet = formset_factory(form=TestForm, max_num=questions.count())
    formset = QuestionFormSet(initial=[{'candidate': request.user, 'question': x.number} for x in questions])
    return render(request, 'testing/communicative.html', locals())
```

Two custom templatetags for each answer (A/B):

```
@register.filter(name='get_answer1')
def get_answer1(question):
    try:
        question = TestModel.objects.get(number=question)
        answer = question.answer_1
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        answer = ''
    return answer


@register.filter(name='get_answer2')
def get_answer2(question):
    try:
        question = TestModel.objects.get(number=question)
        answer = question.answer_2
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        answer = ''
    return answer
```

And template is:

```
{% load test_tags %}
<form id="communicative-test-form" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ question_formset.management_form }}
     {% for form in question_formset.forms %}
        {% crispy form %}
        {{ form.id }}
        <p>{{ form.question.value }}</p>
        <p><label>
           <input type=radio name="form-{{ form.question.value|add:"-1" }}-answer" id='id_form-{{ form.question.value|add:"-1" }}-answer' value="1">
                        {{ form.question.value|get_answer1 }}
           </label></p>
           <p><label>
              <input type=radio name="form-{{ form.question.value|add:"-1" }}-answer" id='id_form-{{ form.question.value|add:"-1" }}-answer' value="2">
                        {{ form.question.value|get_answer2 }}
              </label></p>
      {% endfor %}
      <div style="text-align: right;" class="col-md-12">
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should accept your answer if it solved your problem